# Scala enhanced collections

Tags: scala, collections

I'm interested in does Scala provide convenient way to operate with heterogeneous collections?

Especially variant types and multikey-multimaps.

I know that the first one can be built on top of the nested Either classes `Either[Either[A, B], C]`, and the second one on top of the nested Map classes `Map[A, Map[B, Set[C]]]`, but it seems too complicated to perform update/delete operations directly each time I need them(and I need them quite often).

So I'm looking for a ready to use solution. Or maybe there is a convenient and simple way in the standard library? Anyway if you can advice third-party framework, it is ok too.

Comment: A heterogenous collection is often a sign of code smell - if you need to keep different types in the same collection then they should probably have some common interface - i.e. this should be accomplished through polymorphism. A Map of Maps is known as a Table - [Guava provides an API for this](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html). I'm not aware of a similar API for Scala.

Comment: @Boris the Spider, please don't answer if you are not familiar with the topic. The question was obviousely about Scala, not Java. Also considering variant types(which is a well known way of reaching polymorphism in a number of languages) as a "code smell" seems very controversial.

Comment: I didn't answer, I commented.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Good uses of heterogeneous collections include parameterizing list elements based on index, parameterizing map elements based on the key, or generalizing method signatures. I agree, though, that it can be a blunt instrument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala does not provide facilities to make heterogeneous collections easy to manage.

Rather than using complicated nests of `Either`, where you pick a particular tree structure that is probably meaningless, you should use [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)' `HList`s.  I am not certain you will think this is easy, but it is certainly more compact (once you learn enough shapeless wizardry) than `Either`-trees.

Multi-key maps aren't supported in any common library that I'm familiar with.  There are a lot of possible choices for such maps: are keys hierarchical or redundant?  Is symmetric lookup important (i.e. you can get the mapping `B => C` if you have an `A` key, and `A => C` if you have a `B` key)?  I would only note that it is not that hard to write a wrapper that enables you to define your own methods on whichever form of multi-key map you like.  You will probably have to write your own wrapper to get the behavior you want.  The simplest would just be to provide 2-ary contains and get and update methods:

```
implicit class NestedMapAs2Map[A, B, C](val m: Map[A, Map[B, C]]) extends AnyVal {
  def contains2(a: A, b: B): Boolean = m.get(a).exists(_ contains b)
  def get2(a: A, b: B): Option[C] = m.get(a).flatMap(_.get(b))
  def updated2(a: A, b: B, c: C) = m.updated(a, m.get(a).map(mi => mi.updated(b,c)).getOrElse(Map(b -> c)))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for referring Shapeless. I'll have a look. Regarding Multikey maps. Usually I work with hierarchical keys, and lookups are right-associatively assymetric. Like I have presented in the example above. That's why I'm not sure about efficiency of @RobinGreen's suggestion of using tuples.

Comment: @Eliah - If you want something of the form `A => B => C`, having a map that is `(A,B) => C` is not efficient or convenient.  So, no, tuples are probably not what you want unless you always have both keys in hand.

Answer (score 1):

To create "variant types", you can just use inheritance. To "guarantee" that only N variants will exist (well, from Scala code anyway, Java code isn't prevented from creating more subclasses), you can use a `sealed trait`. If you need to use a type which already exists and can't be modified (and/or moved) to `extend` your trait, you can just wrap it in a `case class` with a single field.

I think you should be able to use value classes (using `extends AnyVal with MyTrait` if `MyTrait` is a *universal trait*) to prevent runtime overhead in this context, but I haven't tried it.

For multikey-multimaps, you can use `Map[(A,B), Set[C]]`. Tuples in Scala can go from 2 values up to 22 values. Alternatively, there is also a `MultiMap` trait which you can mix in to a mutable map.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Robin! Does Map with the tuple keys have the same performance on looking up in contrast with nested Maps approach? The data I'm trying to put in has hierarchical nature.

Comment: It would depend on the data and the `Map` implementation you chose, I suppose. I suggest you benchmark it both ways.

Comment: How would you get a `Map[B, Set[C]]` for a specific `A`?

Comment: Ah, for that you'd have to do something like `.filter(_._1 == a)` the overall `Map[(A, B), Set[C]]`. That wouldn't be particularly efficient (and the resulting `Map` wouldn't have the right type either!)